# URL route matching with Regex

Tags: regex, url, match

I'm trying to build my own URL route matching engine, trying to match routes using regular expressions.

For example, let's consider the scenario where a server application allows to set custom parameterized routes and then execute a function when the route it's being invoked by an HTTP request. The developer could create the following routes:

- `/users/:id/doSomething`
- `/hello/world`
- `/:format/convert`

And each one of them would be associated with a different request handler/function.

Now, on an incoming request, the server should be able to match the requested path to the proper handler. So for example if a client application requests `http://myservice.com/users/john/doSomething`, the server should be able to tell that the requested URL belongs to the `/users/{id}/doSomething` route definition, and then execute the associated handler.

Personally they way I would build the route matcher would be to take the requested URL, loop over the route definitions and, if a definition matches the requested URL, execute the handler. The tricky part is the dynamic parameters matching.

How would you build a regular expression that matches the URL segments?

**EDIT**:

I'm currently using the following regular expression to match segments: `([^/\?])+`.

For example to check if a request path belongs to the first route I would match it against:

`/users/([^/])+/doSomething`

Which is a very permissive regex.

Comment: I'm surprised I have to ask you what you've tried.

Comment: Updated with current implementation.

Comment: @Mark In your programming language isn't there a good function to parse urls? however you can use `\/([^\/\?]+)` as your regex!

Answer (score 5):

#### Solution

First concentrate on **how** the developer could create the routes. What must she type for entering dynamic parameters ? Then writing the dynamic parameters matching will be easier.

#### Example

In Java, I recently worked with Jersey. Here is how one can define an url route:

```
/api/{id:[\dA-F]+}.{type:(?:xml|json|csv)}
```

Some expected urls:

```
/api/EF123.csv
/api/ABC.json
/api/1234567890.xml
```

The matcher would parse the route provided by the developer for finding dynamic parameter using a regex like this:

```
{([^:]+)\s*:\s*(.+?)(?<!\\)}
```

Check the demo: http://regex101.com/r/iH1gY3

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Once done, the matcher can build the regex below on the fly for matching the route:

```
/api/[\dA-F]+\.(?:xml|json|csv)
```